# Technical help for disk space allocation

Tags: installation, windows, disk, support

im trying to install Ubuntu but am facing some problems with data allocations. apparently the current partitions made it such that i cant install this OS without erasing the current one (Windows 7)
this is what the installation menu gives:
dev/sda1 size 161000MB used: 119000MB dev/sda2 size 102MB used 35MB dev/sda3 size 246000MB used 46000 MB dev/sda4 size 237000MB used 3200MB

any tips to quickly get over this? note that i need to keep windows 7 only for a couple of programs, so i dont need to have too much memory for it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to improve the grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is related to [Allocating drive space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30641/allocating-drive-space/30653#30653).

Boot in to windows 7.

Open my computer and see if you can free up any drive (like D drive/E drive which are hard disk partitions).You can correlate the drive naming in windows and linux (reported in question) by comparing the sizes as well. If there is one such drive, move all the data in that drive to another drive and so that you can delete it.

Then ,in windows, Go to Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management'. Locate the drive you identified, select it and delete the partition from the menu. That space will become free space.  Boot using Ubuntu install CD and use that partition to install Ubuntu.

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot! one last question, how much do you recommend to allocate drive space? should i use the entire partition? there's the drag menu where on the left there's (Files 48GB /dev/sda3) and on the right /dev/sda4

thanks a lot and sorry for asking too much questions, i just dont want to take a step i might regret.

Comment: i got this error in the installation: 

The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

any valuable tips? i dont think i was meant to install this ubuntu anyway!

Comment: You should use entire partition you made available from windows for Ubuntu, else will be wasting some space. Now if you like to have different partitions (using advanced menus) you can do that if you by creating logical partitions. both sda3 and sda4 has ~230+GB,that is much more for default ubuntu. (just install will need only 4-5 GB, rest will depend upon what you want to put in disks)